# Concavity of log of determinant plus constant

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I need to prove that the following function is convex:
$$f(X) = -\log\left( \sqrt{\det(A - X^2)} - c  \right)$$
where $X^2, A$ are positive definite $2\times 2$ matrices and $A > X^2$ in the Semidefinite sense and $c$ is a scalar such that the term under logarithm is always positive.
I have looked into similar problems in Boyd's book like the log-determinant example of section 3.1.5 which proves $\log \det(X)$ is concave, but the proof there does not directly apply here because of the $c$ term I cannot turn this into summation over eigenvalues.

One other approach is to use the exercise 3.18 of Boyd which says $\det(X)^{1/n}$ is concave for $X\in S_{++}^n$. Therefore, saying because $A - X^2$ is concave and decreasing then the term inside the $\log$ is convex. Finally because $-\log$ is convex then the whole function is convex. Is this argument correct? Also I am not entirely sure how to prove 3.18 so is it possible to provide some explanation for the whole problem? I would appreciate any help or guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Your argument, after some ironing out of details, can prove that $g(Y)=-\log(\sqrt{\mathrm{det}(A-Y)}-C)$ is convex and even has a conic model. When you replace the affine matrix function with the nonlinear $X^2$ then it looks much trickier, if at all convex.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks for your reply. You may look it this way:
$h(Y) = -\log (\sqrt{\det{(Y)}} - c)$ is concave. Then because $A - X^2$ is a polynomial concave decreasing function, its composition with h(Y) will be convex.

Comment: $A-X^2$ is function with matrix values, so calling it "concave increasing" makes no sense. At this point your argument breaks.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek see for example 3.49 and the argument above it in Boyd's book. It specifically mentions the concept K-nonincreasing and convex exists for matrix expressions. So I don't think that would cause any problem.